# C2DM registrationId handling -Best Practice?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Here's the situation I'm struggling with.  When a user installs my app and runs it for the first time, I register with C2DM and get the registrationID.  I then send it to my server and notifications are sent to the app.

If the user uninstalls the app, then installs it again, a new registration is made to C2DM and I receive a new registrationID.

The problem is, the server now has two registrationID's for the same app and I get multiple/redundant notifications to onMessage.
What is the best practice way of avoiding this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we send the registrationId to our server we generate an identifier that can be constantly reproduced client side to identify the registrationId to the specific user. This also allows us to unregister the user if we wanted the option, as a plus it eliminates your issue.

Comment: I also receive a generated id after registering with the server, but how do you reproduce the id is the app is uninstalled? Are you using the device ID? I wanted to avoid that because device ID will be deprecated soon and generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Also, device ID is not reliable with all versions on Android.

Comment: We use TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() and have no problem with it. We have been doing so since Android came out.

Comment: Yeah, that's the basic approch, the problem is that it wont work on tablets and like I mentioned will not be a reliable approch moving forward.  All mobile devices, Android, iPhone are discouraging the use of device identification in favor of app identification.

Comment: Thanks for the replies though.

Comment: The idea is still to product a reproducible identifier. However you go about creating it is up to the developer.